# Let V be a finite set and let $\Omega \subseteq 2^{V}$ be a nested family of odd subsets of V. Show that $|\Omega| \leq \frac{3}{2}\cdot|V|$.

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

Let V be a finite set and let $\Omega \subseteq 2^{V}$ be a nested family of odd subsets of V, where subset $A\subseteq V$ is odd if |V(A)| is odd (if A has an odd amount of nodes).

**Question:** How do I show that $|\Omega| \leq \frac{3}{2}\cdot|V|$?

I have no clue on how I should tackle this problem, thanks in advance!

Comment: What does it mean for a subset of $V$ to be odd?  That it has an odd number of elements?

Comment: What is a "nested family of odd subsets"? I can sort of imagine what nested means, but odd? When is a subset odd?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thanks, edited!

Comment: What does $V(A)$ mean? What is a node in this context? I don't see any graphs or networks here, just plain sets. Maybe you could give a small example?

Comment: Maybe you'd better define "nested" too. I *thought* I knew what it must mean, but for what I thought it meant we'd have $|\Omega|\le1+|V|$ for *any* nested family.

Comment: @bof, I think the OP might be referring to [intersection graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_graph) on a family of sets.